# PHP web service background image

Tags: php

```
$backgroundimg = URL_PUBLIC.'public/project/images/'.$project->image;
```

I've set the URL as string in `$backgroundimg` and i could not call the background image from my file, i'm 100% very sure the link and file exist and correct.

```
$strresult .= '<div id="list-item'.$lastornot.'" class="item '.$sub_cat.'" style="background-image: url('.$backgroundimg.'); display: block;">
```

I stored all the html code in string and when I hit on click more button all the function i did is shown, just my background image is not shown

When i inspect element, there is only "display:block;" but there is no `background-image` code. How should i correct it ?

Comment: Do you load this via ajax? if so, paste here your output, check it via "Network" tab when you hit F12 in chrome. If it's not ajax, also paste here the output. And check your console to see if there are any errors while loading the image.

Comment: 1
function loadmoreComProject() {
 var htmlResult = '';
 var startIdx = $('#comCurIdx').val();

 req = 'loadmoreComProject';
 var webservice_url = "webservice.php?f=loadmoreComProject&startidx="+startIdx+"&cnt="+rowCount;
 xmlhttp.open('POST', webservice_url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 return false;
}

Comment: after then is link to the webservice.php to do the loading and displaying part which is by storing the normal html code into a string @strresult and after all the validation, i just echo out, every things work fine just the background image is not working

Comment: You didn't show me your output, you showed me your JS code. What is the response of your ajax call?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcvjGt1x2Lc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Before clicking "Load More" go to "Network" tab in your developers tool. Then click your "Load More" button, and you'll see a php request. Choose the request (you can find it by filtering XHR or typing your PHP file name in the search bar) And then update your question and paste the response.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHEQrwvi9Iw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You should click that new added line, then on the right window you will have "Headers" and "Response" tabs. show me the "Response".

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
style="background: url('your-image')";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: when i inspect element, there is only <div id="list-item" class="item office" style="display: block; height: 384px;">, there is no style="background-image:url('my-image')";

Comment: @Clijsters okay I will keep it in mind. I'm very new here so I don't really know what the people expect from me here.

Comment: @Nyyk Before you posted this question, didn't the system suggest you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?